# Redirect all request to (from any domain) to the target domain (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all requests to a single domain.

The target domain should have https and www.

Request examples:

```
http://aaa.de  
http://www.aaa.de  
https://aaa.de  
https://www.aaa.de  

http://bbb.de  
http://www.bbb.de  
https://bbb.de  
https://www.bbb.de  

http://mydomain.de
http://www.mydomain.de
```

All that request should be redirected to: **https://www.mydomain.de**

Comment: is this just for one domain?

Comment: Yes, the website should only run under one domain. The Problem is that the customer adds domains to the webspace from time to time. So i would prevent that it could be reached from any other domain.

Comment: how is your apache setup? So are all these domains setup as alias' to main domain in apache conf?

Comment: Cant tell you. The Domains could be added on the GUI of the Hoster. Than the Website could be accessed on the new Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydomain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to use a new browser for your testing to avoid old browser cahhe.